# reset filtered data in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to reset filtered inventory array, so it displays all the inventories, when clicking on `<option value="">Barcodes</option>` . so far when i choose a barcode, after that it only shows filtered data.

```
$scope.filter = function(barcode) {
        var filtered = [];
        for(var i = 0; i < $scope.inventories.length; i++){
            if($scope.inventories[i].barcode == barcode){
                filtered.push($scope.inventories[i]);
            } 
        }
        $scope.inventories = filtered;
    };

    <select ng-model="inventory.barcode" ng-change="filter(inventory.barcode)">
        <option value="">Barcodes</option>
        <option ng-repeat="inventory in inventories" value="{{inventory.barcode}}">{{inventory.barcode}}</div>
    </select>
```

Comment: You are overwriting all your inventories when applying the filter function, as you replace the $scope.inventories array with the filtered array. Take a look at the angular filter functionality, especially the example: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can filter directly inside the `ng-repeat` using `filter`

```js
$scope.barcode = "";
$scope.conditionalFilter = function(item){
  if ($scope.barcode !== "") {
    return item.barcode === $scope.barcode; // return items only if barcode is selected
  } else {
    return true; // return all items
  } 
};
```

And your HTML will change to

```html
    <select ng-model="barcode">
        <option value="">Barcodes</option>
        <option ng-repeat="inventory in inventories | filter:conditionalFilter" value="{{inventory.barcode}}">{{inventory.barcode}}</option>
    </select>
```

But actually you shouldn't be changing the value of your own element using ng-model

Comment: its alredy filtering in select, but i need to reset filter so when i click on Barcodes it shows all barcodes again

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve. But have a look at [angularjs filter](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter) which will filter for you.
And it is recommended to use ng-options with select rather using ng-repeat.

I have created a sample [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sb_satchitanand/B9W68/) using the filter and ng-options.

```
<div ng-repeat="inventory in inventories| filter : barcode track by $index">
    {{inventory.barcode}}
</div>
```

You can use "track by" in ng-options for getting the inventory.barcode in option "value"

```
<option value=""></option>

<select ng-model="barcode" ng-options="inventory.barcode for inventory in inventories track by inventory.barcode">
    <option value="">Barcodes</option>       
</select>
```

Comment: ok i will check it out at work, and give you a feedback as soon as posible